Add machine-name as css class to my blocks
So I would like to give my blocks the internal machine name of the block as a CSS class? I can add the block ID and the block type as presprocess via theme.theme:
function xxx_theme_preprocess_block(&$variables) {

  // adding custom attribute class for block
  if ($variables['elements']['#base_plugin_id'] == 'block_content') {
    $blockType = strtr($variables['content']['#block_content']->bundle(), '_', '-');
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'block--type-' . $blockType;
  }
}

but how exactly do I get the machine name of the block? Does anyone have a tip for me? Would I like to stick to programming and not install a module, or can I get the machine name more quickly via the Twigtemplate? Would be very grateful for any help.
My Code for the Blocks bei Drupal:
<div id="block-justtransition-theme-testblockhtml" class="contextual-region block--type-block-with-html">

    <div data-contextual-id="block:block=justtransition_theme_testblockhtml:langcode=fr|block_content:block_content=4:changed=1714046004&amp;langcode=fr" data-contextual-token="4vz7RkERDoPBGRz4dHwAsTvYn_cdn7VRwTGz0wUPd18" data-drupal-ajax-container=""></div>
    <div class="field field--label-hidden field--type-text_with_summary field-body">
        <div class="field__content">
            <h2>Test Block html</h2><p><br>Placerat quam eleifend nobis voluptas expedita vero tincidunt, at lobortis, maxime sit magni ab aut purus occaecati per saepe bibendum, odio. Purus illo incididunt, ex anim aliquet? Nam? Irure ac ut incididunt veritatis nostra quisquam, viverra habitasse porro diam ipsam egestas beatae! Aptent metus veniam sunt, tempor sapien, sed dolorum magnam debitis non hac cupidatat ea nonummy faucibus scelerisque modi massa sociosqu pellentesque soluta, integer? Luctus condimentum corporis, unde! Aptent nemo, consectetuer id faucibus assumenda praesentium eaque maiores, proin sed eaque itaque iusto similique habitasse, pede quisquam! Consequat, nihil quis ratione hac! Iste imperdiet, luctus auctor officia labore, quidem! Qui.<br>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div id="block-justtransition-theme-headerimage" class="contextual-region block--type-block-with-html">
    <h2>Header Image</h2>
    <div data-contextual-id="block:block=justtransition_theme_headerimage_4:langcode=fr|block_content:block_content=5:changed=1707486078&amp;langcode=fr" data-contextual-token="jLHhf7x405wmyQvrQTBmFp-Bfto-WY8xLu_L-24l8Go" data-drupal-ajax-container=""></div>
    <div class="field field--label-hidden field--type-text_with_summary field-body">
        <div class="field__content">
            <img data-entity-uuid="520edd47-ea9a-4a58-ae45-26c1992e076c" data-entity-type="file" src="/sites/stage-toumali.adelphi.de/files/inline-images/shutterstock_1891163254_xxxxxxx-_0.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Bavra

Is it a block plugin (code) or a block created through the UI using the Custom Block module?

First of all, thank you for your feedback. I have created the block with the Costum Block module, and created two blocks, one with image and one with html text only.
The two different blocks are used in different orders in their number and sorting and I would like to design the two block types differently with css.

I would actually need another class for this, the ID is of no use to me. They are then always numbered consecutively with -1 or -2 and the numbers appear in the ID.
I was thinking of the machine name, because it is different. Once block_with_html and once block_with_imge. I have included the code of the blocks above. Maybe you have another idea or solution? I would like to avoid installing an extra module for this.

Individual custom blocks (aka block content entities - what you see at admin/content/block) don't have machine names as such, they just have the serial ID. Do you want to style them based on the type of custom block (ie what you see at admin/structure/block-content)?
